# PHP $_POST give empty value

Tags: php

I don't know what happened but there's no value return.
[Please check if i made any mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ6pV.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). [Don't post your code as an image.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: Your code seems correct. what is the output of print_r() ?

Comment: You've posted images of your form and processing script(code should be text), but what about what happens currently?

Comment: the output of print_r() is  empty array() .that why i want to ask why it like this and need some help . for my post I'm sorry I did not read the post description .

Comment: Why would `print_r()` not be empty? **Post** your **ACTUAL** code. Shocked there are only 2 close votes on this ambiguous questsion..

Answer (score -1):

Value is blank if you have no check for null or blank value on transfer.php

Case 1 : You are access file in same flow then no need to modify any thing its wokring.If you are access file without press submit button.directly using url  then post is blank.

e.g. http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/transfer.php

Case 2 : MIME type issue, enctype="text/plain" in the form, this should fix the issue.

**from_post.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="transfer.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**transfer.php**

Here you want to check is that submit button if fired or not.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

     $u=$_POST['name'];
     if(isset($u) || (!is_empty())){

         echo $u;
     }
     else
     {
         echo "the post doesn't have any value";

     }
     echo "<br/>";

 }

?>
```

Comment: Checking `submit` over `name` would make no difference. They both would be set; maybe if OP was using `empty` and the value was `0` that'd make sense.

Comment: why not if you go direct to file insted of click button then it make diffrenace

Comment: Phrase that differently or provide an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: if i directly go to url of `transfer.php` then there is no value.am i right? we need to check is submit button argument is null or not.

Comment: The current `isset` would be sufficient for that. It is hard to say for sure but this seems incorrect. OP should update the question; images of code are insufficient. There should be a clear issue presented and expected result.